# Pytables table into pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, pytables

Lots of information on how to read a csv into a pandas dataframe,  but I what I have is a pyTable table and want a pandas DataFrame.

I've found how to store my pandas DataFrame *to* pytables... then read I want to read it back, at this point it will have:

```
"kind = v._v_attrs.pandas_type"
```

*I could write it out as csv and re-read it in but that seems silly. It is what I am doing for now.*

How should I be reading pytable objects into pandas?

Answer (score 7):

```py
import tables as pt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# the content is junk but we don't care
grades = np.empty((10,2), dtype=(('name', 'S20'), ('grade', 'u2')))

# write to a PyTables table
handle = pt.openFile('/tmp/test_pandas.h5', 'w')
handle.createTable('/', 'grades', grades)
print handle.root.grades[:].dtype # it is a structured array

# load back as a DataFrame and check types
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(handle.root.grades[:])
df.dtypes
```

Beware that your u2 (unsigned 2-byte integer) will end as an i8 (integer 8 byte), and the strings will be objects, because Pandas does not yet support the full range of dtypes that are available for Numpy arrays.

Comment: thanks but how does this read data from a non pandas h5 file into a pandas h5 file?   It looks like it just puts random data into a pandas h5 file.  I can read my source table like this 'for rec in table:'  but the table is not a pandas h5 file it is just a pytable table so it fails as the pandas source because 'kind' is not 'pandas_type.'

Comment: Wait I spend some more time with this...   are you saying all I need to do is add a structured array with extra data type info to my existing pytables table and then it will inport to pandas df?  I really only know how to work with pyTables ...  It keeps data type info in attributes on the leaf object.  if I have this correct how does pandas associate to two leaf objects.  (one with data type info, one with the table of data)

Comment: import numpy as np
grades = np.empty((10,2), dtype=(('name', 'S20'), ('grade', 'u2')))         This must be a bug python does not understand the code

Comment: Sorry, you're right: you have to use a list (`[]`) to group the dtype specification, not a tuple (`()`).

Comment: As to your other questions, I have trouble understanding what you want. I understand the original post as 'I have a PyTables table and I want a Pandas DataFrame with the correct types'. The answer shows that there's no messing with the _v_attrs to do, since PyTables tables load to record arrays whose dtype specifications are understood by Pandas, even if later Pandas only supports 8-byte integers, 8-byte floats, and objects, instead of the full wealth of [numpy dtypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)

Comment: I was hoping to get this to work but a pyTable table where does not provide a len 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(handle.root.my_table.where('my_field == "some string"'))

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'tables.tableExtension.Row' has no len()

Answer (score 5):

The docs now include an excellent section on [using the HDF5 store](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables) and there are some more advanced strategies discussed in the [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/cookbook.html#cookbook-hdf).

It's now relatively straightforward:

```
In [1]: store = HDFStore('store.h5')

In [2]: print store
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: store.h5
Empty

In [3]: df = DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [4]: store['df'] = df

In [5]: store
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: store.h5
/df            frame        (shape->[2,2])
```

And to retrieve from HDF5/pytables:

```
In [6]: store['df']  # store.get('df') is an equivalent
Out[6]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

*You can also [query within a table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#querying-a-table).*